# How to force https and www for Java Webapp on Apache Tomcat

Tags: docker, tomcat, redirect

I try to force https for a Java Webapp on an Apache Tomcat 9 (deployed via Docker on AWS) with a RewriteValve. But is its not working like expected. Additional I would like to implement a redirect from non-www to www.

In the Dockerfile the Ports are exposed:

`EXPOSE 8080 8443`

and on AWS they are mapped to 80 and 443

The web app has an additional endpoint but should be reachable without it

**The Content of the rewrite.config:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:443$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-domain.com$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule /(robots\.txt)$ /robots.txt [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^00\.000\.000\.00$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/(index\.html)$ /endpoint/homepage.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/$ /endpoint/homepage.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /endpoint/$1 [L]
```

**Current behavior:**

http://my-domain/something.html
is redirecting to
https://my-domain/something.html

but

http://my-domain/endpoint/something.html
is not redirecting to
https://my-domain/endpoint/something.html

no redirect from non-www to www

**Desired behavior:**

force https for all URL, included the endpoint-URL

redirect non-www to www

How can I achieve this behavior?